# Is there a way to download videos from YouTube Studio using NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, youtube

After having done a livestream YouTube is processing the video for quite a bit before it is possible to download it in YouTube Studio (download button is greyed out).

Is there a way using the YouTube API v3 or something else to frequently check if the video is downloadable and then download it automatically using NodeJS?

Please note: this is **not** about downloading videos from others. I want to download a livestream from my own channel as soon as it has been fully processed by YouTube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This try this project in the below github repo:

https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any examples on how to check if the livestream has been processed fully by YouTube already to be downloaded? What I would prefer is an API to both download from YoutTube Studio and that is capable of things like moving livestreams from public to private.

Comment: Ok. Forget about the YT Studio part - I am far away from being a YT partner and it seems YT only gives me access to the "good stuff" if I am a partner. ;) I will check out the repo you've posted to see if will do the trick for the first steps. Thanks again!

Comment: Finally had time to look at this more in detail - and yes it solves my problem even without logging in to studio.